# How to forecast the parameters of Nelson Siegel with a constant lambda in R?

Tags: r, lambda

I want to calculate the beta parameters of the Nelson Siegel model, with a fixed lambda. The lambda should be set at 0.609. I have an excel file that contains 54 yield curves. For each yield curve I want to estimate the beta parameters from the Nelson Siegel model.

At first, I tried to use the Nelson.Siegel function from the "YieldCurve" package. However, the function only has two arguments so that I can't get the lambda constant.

Second, I created a function myself to calculate the Nelson Siegel model. I want to minimize the squared difference between the Nelson Siegel yield and the actual yield by changing the beta parameters of the function. I did this in excel by using solver.

The code that I have so far:

```
RTS54_list <- read_xlsx("YieldCurves.xlsx")

nelson_siegel_calculate<-function(theta,lambda,beta0,beta1,beta2){
  beta0 + beta1*(1-exp(-lambda * theta))/(lambda * theta) + beta2*((1-exp(-lambda * theta))/(lambda * theta) - exp(-lambda * theta))
}

ns_data <-
  data.frame(maturity=1:100) %>%
  mutate(NSS=nelson_siegel_calculate(theta=maturity,lambda=0.0609,beta0=0.02,beta1=-0.02,beta2=0.01))
```

How can I do the same thing in R?

Or is there another way to get my result?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the optim() function in R to minimise the sum of the squared differences between the actual yields and nelson_siegel predictions.

I grabbed the [US Treasury yield curve for 2 Jan 2019](https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/pages/TextView.aspx?data=yieldYear&year=2019); converting the month maturity to year fractions, I ended up with the following data frame:

```
    yldmat <- structure(list(maturity = c(0.0833333333333333, 0.166666666666667, 
              0.25, 0.5, 1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 10, 20, 30), yield = c(0.024, 0.024, 
              0.0242, 0.0251, 0.026, 0.025, 0.0247, 0.0249, 0.0256, 0.0266, 
              0.0283, 0.0297)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -12L))
```

Then I created the following minimisation function, with the lambda defaulted to 0.609, and the theta being the same as the 'maturity' value for each curve point:

```
min.ns <- function(data, param) {
    with(data, sum((yield - nelson_siegel_calculate(maturity, 0.609, param[1], param[2], param[3]))^2))
}
```

Now I can invoke the optim() routine with the initial parameter set 0.02, -0.02, 0.01 for the betas, per your example:

```
optim(par = c(0.02,-0.02,0.01), fn = min.ns, data = yldmat)
$par
[1]  0.029152661 -0.004403284 -0.007526309

$value
[1] 7.983234e-06

$counts
function gradient 
     132       NA 

$convergence
[1] 0

$message
NULL
```

The $par values are those for beta0, beta1, beta2 that you want.